# Can we have some way of getting the count from each of the bars in the survey?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2019

In the [Social Media Use](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-social-media-use) section of [the survey results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019) there are two values with "0.0%" as their values.

Given that the total number of responses (84,437) is provided, all that we can ascertain is the number of users of [Hello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_(social_network)) and [Youku Tudou 优酷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tudou) are in the range [0, 42]<sup>*</sup> - but don't have any means to compare them because we have one significant figure's worth of information.

> [image]

Could this extra information be added in, say, a tooltip for each bar?

---

<sup>*</sup>43 and above would be rounded to 0.1%

Comment: No tooltips? This cannot be Stack Overflow. *Everything* has tooltips here. Kill the imposter!

Comment: Definitely an imposter. Look at those tabs: they look like tabs not buttons.

Answer (score 8):

This is a borderline naa, but is too much information to put in the comments.

By inspecting the HTML of the graph, it is possible to get more detailed percentages from the bars by looking at their widths. So with a bit of math, the following is possible:

The top bar always has a width of 100%.

In the social media case, this is Reddit with 17%, or roughly 14,354 responses.

By inspecting, I know that the Youku Tudou 优酷 bar has a width of 0.1463%. So based on that, I'm assuming that 0.1463% of Reddit's responses equals the amount of responses for Youku Tudou 优酷. This gives 21.

Applying the same logic to Hello, which has a width of 0.1322%, I get 19 responses.

*Disclaimer: This is all assuming that these widths are reliable data points.*

Comment: Good spot. Should probably mention *how* you're inspecting the graph (I initially thought you mentioned a visual inspection (measuring pixels) rather than the HTML itself. Given that doing this for all the bars in all the graphs is unfeasible I'm not sure I can mark this as an answer, though.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yes, this is just a hack to get round the lack of information. I don't consider this a proper answer either, hence my opening line :)